# not displaying markers whats the error..?

Tags: google-maps

Map markers not displaying at all whats the error m using lat long from the database

```js
<script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?PHP echo json_encode($output,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)?>);
  var poss = new google.maps.LatLng(15,78);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: poss
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  for(i = 0;i < myLatlng.length;i++ ) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:new google.maps.LatLng( myLatlng[i][0], myLatlng[i][1]),
      map: map,
  });
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: is there some error in the code????

Comment: What does the code the browser sees look like?  (what is `<?PHP echo json_encode($output,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)?>`, that doesn't look like it would resolve to two floating point numbers, which is what the `google.maps.LatLng` constructor expects).

Comment: [8.6,105.65],[14,109.38],[16.83,108.62],[8.3,104.88],[8.97,106.88]]);
  var poss = new google.maps.LatLng(15,78);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: poss
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
 
  for(i = 0;i < myLatlng.length;i++ ) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:new google.maps.LatLng( myLatlng[i][0], myLatlng[i][1]),
      map: map,
  });
  };
}

</script>

Comment: Please, please, please, don't post code in the comments.  Edit your question with the requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the definition of the `myLatlng` array. Remove the `google.maps.LatLng` from around that array (a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes two numbers, not an array).

```
<script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = <?PHP echo json_encode($output,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)?>;
  var poss = new google.maps.LatLng(15,78);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: poss
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  for(i = 0;i < myLatlng.length;i++ ) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:new google.maps.LatLng( myLatlng[i][0], myLatlng[i][1]),
      map: map,
  });
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**working code snippet (no PHP):**

```js
var myLatlng = [
  [8.6, 105.65],
  [14, 109.38],
  [16.83, 108.62],
  [8.3, 104.88],
  [8.97, 106.88]
];

function initialize() {
  var poss = new google.maps.LatLng(15, 78);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: poss
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < myLatlng.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(
        myLatlng[i][0],
        myLatlng[i][1]),
      map: map,
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body,
html,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```